# Updating a link on clicking another link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am new to JQuery. As I click the first link it sends an Ajax request to the server and gets back with some data. Everything is good so far. In the callback, I want to change the diplay text of second link. for example - 6 people liked it. I searched a lot but could not get it working.

```
<div class="container" id="some-id">
    <a class="someclass-1">Like</a>
    <a class="someClass-2">5 people liked it</a>
</div>
```

I tried something like to change the text of the second link. But I am unable to change the text. My question is just how I select and change the text of the second link.

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.someClass-2').html('6 people liked it');
```

My Ajax code is something like:

```
$(".someClass-1").click(function(e) {
      if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
          var parameters = { statusId: $(this).closest('div').attr('some-id')};
          $.get(
              "/like",
              parameters,
              function(data) { 
               $(this).closest('div').find('.someClass-2').html( data + ' people liked it.');
              }
          );
      }
```

I have many more links of class `someClass-2` on the page but I do not want to disturb them. I just want to change the text of the `someClass-2` link in the current `div`.

Comment: where is your php code?

Comment: how is your ajax call look?

Comment: Is the problem getting data from Ajax, or is your problem in selecting right element and changing text in it?

Comment: My problem is selecting the right element and changing the text in it. editing the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `$(this)`? If you have unique identifier, use it.

```
$(".someClass-2").text("6 people liked it");
```

And of course, put that in Ajax `success` function.

EDIT:

```
var dataNumber;

$(".someClass-1").click(function(e) {
  myElement = $(this);
      if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
          var parameters = { statusId: $(this).closest('div').attr('some-id')};
          $.get(
              "/like",
              parameters,
              function(data) { 
               myElement.siblings('.someClass-2').html( data + ' people liked it.');
              }
          );
      }
```

Use `.siblings()` for selecting all siblings and than filter it by class or `.next()` if you need to select only next sibling.

Also, be careful where you put `this` selector... You have put it in Ajax call, not in `click()` function and because of that it changed it's value.

Comment: If you really need to use this relative selector, let us know and put your whole Ajax call code.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.  `.next()` did not work but `.sibling()` worked fine.

Comment: Great! Accept my answer if that's what you needed. ;) And also - consider up-voting all answers which you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `next()`

```
$(this).next('.someClass-2').html('6 people liked it');
```

with ajax create a variable with the current element:

```
$(".someClass-1").click(function(e) {
      var el =  $(this);///see here
      if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
          var parameters = { statusId: $(this).closest('div').attr('some-id')};
          $.get(
              "/like",
              parameters,
              function(data) { 
              el.next('.someClass-2').html( data + ' people liked it.');//if you use $(this) i will refer to the ajax object
              }
          );
      }
```

or:

```
 $(".someClass-1").click(function(e) {
          var el =  $(this);///see here
          if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
              var parameters = { statusId: $(this).closest('div').attr('some-id')};
              $.get(
                  "/like",
                  parameters,
                  function(data) { 
                  el.parent().find('.someClass-2').html( data + ' people liked it.');//if you use $(this) i will refer to the ajax object
                  }
              );
          }
```

Comment: try the second option

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.someClass-2').html('6 people liked it');`
```

to this

```
$(this).parent().children("a.someClass-2").text("new text");
```

Comment: This will change all the links' texts having class 'someClass-2'. I just want to change the text of the link in the current div

Comment: `$(this).parent().children("a.someClass-2").text("new text"); ` It is not clear from your html that there are more than one elements of this class

Comment: this will change all your `a.someClass-2` elements on the page

Comment: @Nitrin Aggrawal - accept pls. @madalin ivascu - see comment - this will only change all the `a.someClass-2` in the current parent

Comment: you can at least update your answer man ,this answer will work if $(this) is refering to the a element not to the ajax object

Comment: I accepted. But because I am a new user, it is not displaying it publicly. Once I get 15 reputation, it will be shown as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I think This will help you

```
$('#some-id .someClass-2').text('6 people liked it');
```

it will replace html of all someclass-2 in #some-id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$('.someClass-2').html('6 people liked it');
```

...but it's not clear to me where to put that line in your code.

Comment: That will change the text of all the link with the 'someClass-2' class .

Comment: This will change all the links' texts having class 'someClass-2'. I just want to change the text of the link in the current div